# Char* related memory leak

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks

I am running Valgrind to check my code for memory leaks. Valgrind doesn't show any leaks happening but I have a piece of code that I believe should be causing a leak and I don't understand how the variables are being cleaned up or Valgrind isn't catching it. Why do the two char* arrays not create a leak?

```
void BasicEngine::ConnectionInput(int ConnectionId, const char* ClientInput)
{

    // find client assignment to this ConnectionId
    Client* thisClient = this->ClientFind(ConnectionId);

    int SpaceLocation = strcspn(ClientInput," ");

    char* verb;
    char* args;

    if(SpaceLocation == strlen(ClientInput))
    {
        verb = (char*)ClientInput;
        args = (char*)"";
    }
    else
    {
        verb = new char[SpaceLocation+1];
        args = new char[strlen(ClientInput)-SpaceLocation+1];

        sscanf(ClientInput,"%s %[^\n]",verb,args);
    }


    if(thisClient != NULL)
    {    
       // ... client is always null, this is not being reached at the moment.
    }
    else   
    {
        if(this->refCmdHandler != NULL)
         if(this->refCmdHandler->cmdHandler(ConnectionId,ClientInput))
            return;
    }

    this->refServer->TransmitNL(ConnectionId,"Invalid Command.");

}


bool BasicCmdProc::cmdHandler(int ConnectionId, string ClientInput)
{
    Transmit(ConnectionId,string("You Said: ") + ClientInput);

    return true;
}
```

If I type in 'hello'

output is: You said: hello

and no leaks are detected.

Comment: Why are you using arrays not `vector` s anyway?

Comment: Did you mean `string`, @BartekBanachewicz?  A `vector<char>` would be an unusual way to handle strings, I think.

Comment: That's probably late evening + me doing too much of strange IO lately.

Answer (score 3):

`hello` contains no spaces, so `strcspn` returns `strlen(ClientInput)` and so you take the first branch. In that branch, `verb` and `args` are not dynamically allocated, so there's no leak.

Note, however, that it is usually very dangerous to have a variable point at "maybe-allocated" memory, because it will be harder to determine if the variable should be freed. You should therefore use `new` in both branches, and unconditionally free both variables at the end. Or, better yet, use `std::string`s and avoid this issue altogether.

Comment: I tried 'hello world' as input but still get the same result of no memory leak. Could passing the char* array to a string parameter have some affect on this? Its the only thing I could come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the two `char *` elements `verbs` or `args` is allocated when the input is `hello` because:

```
int SpaceLocation = strcspn(ClientInput," ");

char* verb;
char* args;

if (SpaceLocation == strlen(ClientInput))
{
    verb = (char*)ClientInput;
    args = (char*)"";
}
else
{
    verb = new char[SpaceLocation+1];
    args = new char[strlen(ClientInput)-SpaceLocation+1];

    sscanf(ClientInput,"%s %[^\n]",verb,args);
}
```

the output from `strcspn(ClientInput, " ")`, aka `SpaceLocation`, is the same as `strlen(ClientInput)`, so the `new[]` operation is not executed and no memory is allocated.

How will you tell whether or not you need to release `verb` and `args`?  Not knowing whether to release memory is dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

> Why do the two char* arrays not create a leak?

They only do when you assign the result of the `new` operator to them (and in this case, Valgrind should be notifying you). If you assign constant strings to them, then there's no memory to be leaked - constant strings are alive under the whole lifetime of the program.